# Receive data only if available in Python sockets

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I want to receive data only if it is available. like `Serial.available()` in Arduino. I want code like this:

```
if there is data:
     receive and print
else:
     print 'No data'
```

In fact, I do not want the program to stop just for receiving data.

Comment: use non-blocking sockets or set a timeout on the socket.

Comment: Call `recv()` with the flag `MSG_DONTWAIT`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call `.setblocking(False)` on a socket to disable blocking mode.  The call will raise a `BlockingIOError` when it would otherwise block.  But then you have to handle exceptions when you `.accept()` or `.recv()` on the socket and there is no connection ready or no data to receive.

For example:

```
try:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print(data)
except BlockingIOError:
    print('no data')
```

`select.select` can be used to poll multiple sockets for data.  Here's a quick example:

```py
import socket
import select

server = socket.socket()
server.bind(('', 8000))
server.listen()
readables = [server] # list of readable sockets.  server is readable if a client is waiting.
i = 0
while True:
    # to_read will be a list of sockets with readable data
    to_read, to_write, errors = select.select(readables, [], [], 0)
    for sock in to_read: # iterate through readable sockets
        if sock is server: # is it the server?
            client, address = server.accept()
            print(f'\r{address}: connected')
            readables.append(client) # add the client
        else:
            # read from address client
            data = sock.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                print(f'\r{sock.getpeername()}: disconnected')
                readables.remove(sock)
                sock.close()
            else:
                print(f'\r{sock.getpeername()}: {data}')
    # a simple spinner to show activity
    i += 1
    print(r'/-\|'[i%4], end='\r', flush=True)
```

Example where two clients connected, sent something and disconnected:

```
('127.0.0.1', 2983): connected
('127.0.0.1', 2983): b'hello'
('127.0.0.1', 2985): connected
('127.0.0.1', 2985): b'there'
('127.0.0.1', 2983): disconnected
('127.0.0.1', 2985): disconnected
<spinner activity here>
```

Comment: `recv()` with `MSG_DONTWAIT` is even simpler ...

Comment: @user207421 If it exists.  I only see `['MSG_BCAST', 'MSG_CTRUNC', 'MSG_DONTROUTE', 'MSG_ERRQUEUE', 'MSG_MCAST', 'MSG_OOB', 'MSG_PEEK', 'MSG_TRUNC', 'MSG_WAITALL']` defined in `sockets`.

Comment: I found it via a direct link from the Python `socket.recv()` documentation.

Comment: @user207421 It's Linux-specific.  It's not defined on Windows.  I directly queried `sockets` with `[x for x in dir(sockets) if x.startswith('MSG')]`.